# Postback pixel on page

Tags: javascript, php, postback

I'm completely lost here with how a postback pixel works, or how to trigger it.

I've been given this postback pixel:

```
http://theirtrackerlink.com/path/postback.php?tid=1&offerid=&amount={payout}&subid={subid}
```

Now, I can substitute the variables on my pages, but how do I then call the postback pixel?

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Postback pixels are handled with server to server interactions. So in your case, calling the postback link with PHP, using `file_get_contents('http://theirtrackerlink.com/path/postback.php?tid=1&offerid=&amount={payout}&subid={subid}');` should suffice.

Comment: Tried both answers, and they both worked great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `tag manager` plugins for most setups that mean you can managed these in one central place.
The basic way to implement is create a 1px × 1px img with that as the src.

```
<img width=1 height=1 src="http://theirtrackerlink.com/path/postback.php?tid=1&offerid=&amount={payout}&subid={subid}" />
```

It's often referred to as a tracking 'pixel' because it is implemented through that 1px image tag. The idea is that by requesting the image from that location, you send a request to their server with the information they require to track what they're interested in. It means you don't need another script or plugin on your site.

Comment: Dave's example of using `file_get_contents` may be a solution for purely server side information. However a tracking or postback 'pixel' service can also track user-agent information. If that is important, you either need to fake the headers to appear as a request from the client's browser, or simply let the browser request the pixel and the relevant information will go with that request.